# compare two arrays and delete data that is not in other array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I am new to the Apps script and trying to compare two email lists,
emails from google contacts
and emails from a google sheet (column B),

I want to delete email/s from Google Contacts that are not listed in the google sheet.
I got partial code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953554/delete-duplicated-or-multiplied-contacts-from-google-contacts) and trying to modify it for my use, however, I stuck in the last part to detect the email that is not in the google sheet and then delete it from google contact.
Here is what I could put together, Extracting emails from Google contacts and Google sheet works fine.
running the following code does not work, but I don't get any error either.

Edited: I am not sure the first part of the code that extracts data from google contacts is in one array, because each email is printed like this when used console.log: [email1@email.com]

Appreciate your help to make it work.

```
function deleteContacts() {
 var contactEmails = ContactsApp.getContacts().map(function(contact) {
   return contact.getEmailAddresses();
        //console.log("Google Emails:" + contactEmails);

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet2"); 
 var ColEmails = sheet.getRange('B2:B').getValues().map(function(value) {
   return value[0];
 }).filter(function(val) {
   return val != "";
 })
        //console.log("Sheet Emails:" + ColEmails);
 
for (var i = 0; i < contactEmails.length; i++) {
   if (ColEmails.indexOf(contactEmails[i]) == -1) {
     var contact = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(contactEmails[i]);
     ContactsApp.deleteContact(contact);
   }
 }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function deleteContacts() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  const vs = rg.getValues().flat();
  const emails = ContactsApp.getContacts().map(function (contact) {return contact.getEmailAddresses();}).flat();
  emails.forEach(e=>{
    if(!~vs.indexOf(e)) {
      ContactsApp.getContact(e).deleteContact()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it does not work, no error either,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, I did, there is no error there.

Comment: Thanks for your new code, I tried it, I get this error: `TypeError: vs.index is not a function`